# How to turn on Template Path Hints in Magento2 Through Code edit

Tags: magento2, theme, template, template-hints

I know that you can turn template path hints on in Magento2 through the Admin Panel at *Stores > Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer*.

Although in Magento 1 I find it much quicker to temporarily edit a single line of code in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php`.  At line 200 I simply change:

```
return self::$_showTemplateHints;
```

to

```
return true;
```

It saves a lot of time than going through the admin panel.  Is there somewhere in Magento 2 where I can similarly turn on Template Path hints by editing a line of code this way?

Answer (score 1):

I like [ho-nl/magento2-Ho_Templatehints](https://github.com/ho-nl/magento2-Ho_Templatehints), you can get the required info without breaking the layout

[image: ho-nl/magento2-Ho_Templatehints]

Answer (score 1):

**I strongly discourage this. Use at your own risk. Only to be used on local system.**

Open `vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/TemplateEngine/Plugin/DebugHints.php` (tested in 2.3.2)

write this code inside `afterCreate` function : (at the start, above the storecode line)

```
if(isset($_GET['shreyasPathHints']) && $_GET['shreyasPathHints'] == 'on'){
    return $this->debugHintsFactory->create([
        'subject' => $invocationResult,
        'showBlockHints' => 1,
    ]);
}
```

Now, you can open any magento page and append `?shreyasPathHints=on` to the url. No need to run any commands.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: use MageRun 2: https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2

Then you can just do:

```
n98-magerun2.phar dev:template-hints enable
```

And to disable:

```
n98-magerun2.phar dev:template-hints disable
```

But to answer your question, [**even if I strongly discourage that**](https://magenticians.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Ben-Marks-Magento.png), just edit `app/code/Magento/Developer/Model/TemplateEngine/Plugin/DebugHints.php` and replace in the constructor:

```
$this->debugHintsPath = $debugHintsPath;
```

With:

```
$this->debugHintsPath = true;
```

Comment: thanks but editing _vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/TemplateEngine/Plugin/DebugHints.php_ did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's saved in DB.

In table `core_config_data`, there are those 3 lines:

```
ID | default | 0 | dev/debug/template_hints_storefront | 1/0
ID | default | 0 | dev/debug/template_hints_admin      | 1/0
ID | default | 0 | dev/debug/template_hints_blocks     | 1/0
```

In value column it's bool 1 or 0. You can write quick and dirty script to change that. Also there is plenty of tools that can help you with that.

If you use PhpStorm I would recomend http://www.magicento.com/ plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend [Easy Template Path Hints](http://www.magepsycho.com/magento-2-easy-template-path-hints.html). It enables template path hints in magento 2 by just appending  `?tp=1`  in url and you can also add access code from admin configuration if you are thinking someone else would enable it.

It is very handy for frontend development.

Comment: that extension is for Magento 1 only, not Magento 2

Comment: Sorry about that refer to this link instead
http://www.magepsycho.com/magento-2-easy-template-path-hints.html or you can get it directly from [github](https://github.com/MagePsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't edit code because at the end you will forget to remove it.
Although I don't find template-hints useful anyway.
It's strange such things don't exist in the command-line already but well..
You should add a new cli command to turn template-path hints on and off.

See:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/cli-cmds/cli-howto.html